# Determining the number and order of all cyclic subgroup $Z_5 \oplus Z_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Problem says:

> Determine (without creating the subgroup lattce) the number and order
>   of all cyclic subgroups of $Z_5 \oplus Z_{15}$.

To solve it, I use the following theorem:

> Every subgroup of a cyclic group $G$ is cyclic. Furthermore, if $G$ is
>   finite with $|G|=n$, then all the subgroups of $G$ consist of $<z^d>$
>   for all divisors $d$ of $n$  and where $z $ is a generator of $G$

So, if I could show that $Z_5 \oplus Z_{15}$ is cyclic, it's done. Since $|Z_5 \oplus Z_{15}|=75$, there exists subgroups $<g^d>$ where $d=1,3,5,15,25,75$.

But I can't show that $Z_5 \oplus Z_{15}$ is cyclic. I take $(1,1)$ as a candidate of generator. However, it seems that it's not a desired one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $G=\mathbb{Z}_5\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is not cyclic. If $(a,b)$ were a generator of $G$ then there would exists $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m\cdot (a,b)=(ma,mb)=(1,0)$ and $n(a,b)=(na,nb)=(0,1)$. Thus, $na\equiv 0 \mod 5$ which implies $n=5k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then, we have $$nb=5k(b)\equiv 1 \mod 15,$$ that is, $5k\cdot b - 1=15 q$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is a contradiction, because we would have $1=5(kb-3q)$, implying that $5$ divides $1$.

To characterize all cyclic groups of $G$, have in mind that by definition a group is cyclic if it has only one generator. So if $G'=\langle (a,b)\rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$, you will have necessarily that $$5\cdot (a,b)=(5a,5b)=(0,5b).$$ On the other hand, $G'$ is exactly the set $\{(a,b),2(a,b),\ldots,m(a,b)=(0,0)\}$ where $m$ is minimal such that $m(a,b)=(0,0)$. Hopefully this will give you some intuition to solve the problem.

Comment: It's really helpful. Thanks a lot!